# iOS Attention Aware Features usage

Tags: ios, swift, vision, face-id

How can I detect if the user's attention is on iphone. The same function as the faceID, detect if the user is looking at the iphone.

Tried the vision framework but I was not successfull. Any code or documentation would be very helpful.